# How to install external Clojure dependencies locally in a project?

Tags: clojure, dependencies, local

In Clojure, how do I install dependencies in a folder (lets call it ./deps) that is in the same folder as deps.edn?

I am looking for a way to have the dependencies saved (downloaded) somewhere in the folder structure of the project I am working on.

I tried setting :local/root from the instructions on [here](https://clojure.org/reference/deps_and_cli#deps_sources) but that did not work.  It still installed the dependencies in ~/.m2.

Comment: What kind of deps do you mean: external repos, where you want to develop
along inside your main project? Or jars, that are no published somewhere
public? ...  Please add what you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: Why would you think that you’d want to do this? I think we need to get to the actual goal you are trying to accomplish, this sounds like a distraction that is a symptom of an XY Problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: Ruby, Python, Node, ... all have ways to install dependencies in the project file structure as where my src files are.  It is the idea of global vs local install of dependencies.

Comment: I would perhaps argue that there are special cases where you _really_ do not want your dependency resolution to break even if you leave your repo for twenty years and come back to it later. I have had this happen more than once where a build that used to work on some ancient project now no longer does so because of some subtle change in dependency resolution. One solution of course is to download all deps, check them in, and resolve against this "local repo". Yes I know, not how we usually think about things, but if you are freezing a project for long term storage, this is one option.

Comment: yep, see my comment in the answer about why I want to do this.  It is in line with what you mentioned with a few other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for `:mvn/local-repo "deps"` in the `deps.edn` top level map. Your question is a bit vague, but this will install all your project dependencies in the project `deps` dir, instead of the usual `~/.m2` default.

Comment: apologies for the vagueness.  Ruby, Python, Node all have ways to install dependencies in the same folder as src files.  I was looking for a way to do that in clojure.  So if I have a project I am working on with my source files, the dependencies are saved somewhere in the folder structure of my project along with as the code I am writing.  I edited the question.  Hopefully it is less vague.  Thanks

Comment: The Java world doesn't work like that. Dependencies are declared in a project and fetched as needed, and the tooling squirrels them away in a standard folder.

I guess the question is: why do you think you want to do this, rather than working in the standard way with JVM-based tooling?

Comment: To me, it is better organization. I don’t want to have a bunch of packages/dependancies on my system, I am not using anymore. I would rather have applications that I built that I am not using anymore. So when it is time to remove unused apps I built, I am removing the dependancies with them. Also, I do not want to remove a dependencies that are used by an app on my system that I am not aware of; then have to download it again (no guarantee it is the same file or will be available). Also, if jars have source files, it is easier to navigate, when working in project.

Comment: I am sure there are other reasons, but those are all I can think of, off the top of my head. I know there are pros and cons. I am ok with having the same dependancies download individually for multiple projects.

Comment: Your edit talks about `:local/root`, but my answer was `:mvn/local-repo`. I'm not sure which one you actually tried. `:local/root` doesn't seem to be what you are looking for based on your previous comments here. So, just `{:mvn/local-repo "deps" :paths [...] :deps {...}}`.

Comment: @ThomasHeller, you are right. I got the dependancies installed in a deps folder of my project. I think I read your answer wrong, initially.  I thought you wanted me to change where dependencies would end up globally, but you actually mentioned that it would be placed it in my project deps folder.  Thank you so much.  I did get an error at the end of the process "Could not locate my_proj/clj__init.class, my_proj/clj.clj or my_proj/clj.cljc on classpath."  But I think I may be able to figure that one out hopefully.  If not I will post another question.

Comment: I would still encourage you to learn to not want to do this in the Java ecosystem, and accept that the standard place where dependencies are managed is a cache that you generally should not think about or worry about. It will make your life easier and smoother.

Comment: "then have to download it again (no guarantee it is the same file or will be available)." -- while that may not be a reliable process with some languages you've used, it is extremely reliable in the Java world. Artifacts do not get randomly deleted or replaced with different versions in the Java world.